# Setting Query Parameteres in REST

Tags: spring, rest, apache-camel, dsl, restlet

I am using restlet to consume a URL.

I am creating a dynamic URL and with XML DSL.

Even if I hard code the parameter values like below

```
<toD uri="restlet:https://---URL---:443/claims/id/?userId=1&amp;id=25?restletMethod=GET" />
```

I am getting the following error

```
Restlet operation failed invoking https://---URL---:443/employee/id/?id=25%3FrestletMethod%3DGET&userId=1
```

How do I set parameters to these dynamic URLs ?

Comment: Be aware restlet is deprecated(https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/restlet-component.html) maybe you should use http or http4 components instead.
If you stay with restlet, you could construct the URI by setting the CamelHttpUri header with a value.

Comment: Beware, you have *multiple* question marks in your uri: ?userId=...?restletMethod=GET !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a second question mark (?) in your query string. ie: id=25?restletMethod=GET

```
<toD uri="restlet:https://---URL---:443/claims/id/?userId=1&amp;id=25?restletMethod=GET" />
```

You should probably replace that with another ampersand ( id=25&restletMethod=GET)